# error when parsing apk using apkParser php class in server

Tags: php, parsing, apk

i use apk parser for parsing apk files

you can get it free from : 
[download apk parser php class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7432-PHP-Extract-Application-Package-files-in-APK-format.html)

in localhost i use xampp and it work very good!

but in server when i want user it show me this error:

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 17179869219

Filename: lib/ApkXmlParser.php

Line Number: 160

in package there are many examples i use that examples but in server don't work!